# JPA Mapping OneToMany between composite key with diferent column names

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I trying to make a jpa model from a LEGACY database schema.

I have created a simple database in mysql and I generated the model using jpa tools in eclipse (Reverse).

The code generated by jpa tool give an error in my springboot project:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(id) of stackoverflow.entity.SecondTable.mainTable 
referencing stackoverflow.entity.MainTable NOT MAPPED TO A SINGLE PROPERTY

I think it make sense because in SecondTable my PK is (id, day) and in MainTable is (id, year, month, code). 
Right now the idea is to have the id’s related.

Several links:
https://gigsterous.github.io/engineering/2016/09/25/spring-boot-2.html

For attribute override (maybe specify which column is not related)
http://techqa.info/programming/question/33620473/hibernate-bidirectional-one-to-many-with-composite-key

[JPA: Entity mapping with composite primary key and single key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437617/jpa-entity-mapping-with-composite-primary-key-and-single-key)

These are the 4 entities created by jpa tool:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="main_table")
public class MainTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private MainTablePK id;

    private String comment;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to SecondTable
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mainTable")
    private List<SecondTable> secondTables;

    public MainTable() {
    }

}

@Embeddable
public class MainTablePK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;

    private String year;

    private String month;

    private String code;

    public MainTablePK() {
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="second_table")
public class SecondTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private SecondTablePK id;


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to MainTable

    //I think I don’t need a bi-directional relationship, just from MainTable to SecondTable

    //ERROR: NOT MAPPED TO A SINGLE PROPERTY
    //I understand id in MainTable is a composite Key
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private MainTable mainTable;


    public SecondTable() {
    }
}


@Embeddable
public class SecondTablePK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;

    private int day;

    private int value1;

    private int value2;

    private int value3;

    public SecondTablePK() {
    }
}
```

SCRIPT SQL and example of data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `main_table`;
CREATE TABLE `main_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `year` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `month` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `code` char(6) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`year`,`month`,`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `main_table` VALUES (1,'2017','01','333090','coment one');

This has a composite key

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `second_table`;
CREATE TABLE `second_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`day`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `second_table` VALUES (1,0,1,NULL,NULL),(1,1,2,NULL,NULL),(1,2,NULL,NULL,NULL),(1,3,NULL,NULL,NULL),(1,4,NULL,NULL,NULL),(1,32,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Is possible to implement using JPA?
Any suggestion?

Thanks

UPDATE

Removed the non-PK fields value1, value2, and value3, was a typo.

Following the JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1 the example 2, page 34,35 is very similar to mine.

So applying:

```
@MapsId("empPK")
              @JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name="FK1", referencedColumnName="firstName"),
@JoinColumn(name="FK2", referencedColumnName="lastName") })
```

we have:

```
@ManyToOne
@MapsId("id") // maps the 'id' attribute of the embedded ID
@JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
private MainTable mainTable;
```

No more changes done.

I get next error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: **Unable to find column reference in the @MapsId mapping: code**

If I remove code, the same error but with **month**, If I remove month, the same error with **year**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, it appears your `SecondTablePK` is incorrect, as it includes the non-PK fields `value1`, `value2`, and `value3`. It should probably look like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class SecondTablePK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;

    private int day;

    public SecondTablePK() {
    }
}
```

As to the shared `id`: Typically, the dependent entity will reference the parent entity's *entire* primary key, but you might be able to map the relationship like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="second_table")
public class SecondTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private SecondTablePK id;

    private int value1;

    private int value2;

    private int value3;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("id") // maps the 'id' attribute of the embedded ID
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private MainTable mainTable;


    public SecondTable() {
    }
}
```

This much like a "derived identity", which is discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.

Comment: Updated my question because I get an error with your suggestion. thxs

Comment: That smells a bit like Hibernate is expecting `SecondTablePK ` to include the entire primary key (i.e. `private MainTablePK mainTable` instead of the "partial key" `private int id`). It is a bit problematic that your foreign key includes only *part* of `MainTable`'s primary key....

Comment: Well, it seems this is not possible according another post with something similar, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245223/jpa-joincolumn-one-to-many-bi-directional-relationship-with-a-composite-key-as , thanks anyway